# Java Swing UI component Layout issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am working on java swing and I am stuck with a UI layout

My current output is as below. The text area after Label 6 is getting shrunk and the next panel is coming beside it. 
What I want is the panel should come in the next line and the text area should be of the same size as the combo boxes.

[image]

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Sample Frame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1000, 800);
frame.setVisible(true);

JPanel jpOPanel = new JPanel();
jpOPanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new TitledBorder("Outer Panel"),
                                      new EmptyBorder(0, 2, 2,
                                                      2)));
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
jpOPanel.setLayout(gbl);

JPanel jpSearch = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
JButton jbSearch = new JButton("Search");
jpSearch.add(jbSearch);
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.fill = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jpSearch, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jpSearch);

JLabel jlLabel1 = new JLabel("Label 1 :");
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.fill = 2;
gbc.gridwidth = -1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel1, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel1);

JComboBox jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jComboBox1, gbc);
jComboBox1.setVisible(true);
jpOPanel.add(jComboBox1);

JLabel jlLabel2 = new JLabel("Label 2 :");
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.gridwidth = -1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel2, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel2);

JComboBox jComboBox2 = new JComboBox();
gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jComboBox2, gbc);
jComboBox2.setVisible(true);
jpOPanel.add(jComboBox2);

JLabel jlLabel3 = new JLabel("Label 3 :");
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.gridwidth = -1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel3, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel3);

JComboBox jComboBox3 = new JComboBox();
gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jComboBox3, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jComboBox3);

JLabel jlLabel4 = new JLabel("Label 4 :");
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.gridwidth = -1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel4, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel4);

JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();
jTextField1.setEditable(false);
gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jTextField1, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jTextField1);

JLabel jlLabel5 = new JLabel("Label 5 :");
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.gridwidth = -1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel5, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel5);

JTextField jTextField2 = new JTextField();
jTextField2.setEditable(false);
gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jTextField2, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jTextField2);

JLabel jlLabel6 = new JLabel("Label 6 :");
jlLabel6.setVisible(true);
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel6, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jlLabel6);

JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea(3, 35);
jTextArea1.setVisible(true);
jTextArea1.setEditable(false); 
jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
int v = ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS;
int h = ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;

JScrollPane jspane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea1, v, h);
gbc.weightx = 2;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbc.gridheight = 2;
gbl.setConstraints(jTextArea1, gbc);
jpOPanel.add(jspane);
jspane.setVisible(true);

JPanel jInnerPanel = new JPanel();
jInnerPanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new TitledBorder(""), new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0)));
gbc.weightx = 0.0D;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
gbc.fill = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jInnerPanel, gbc);

JCheckBox jCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("Check here");
jCheckBox1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
jCheckBox1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
jCheckBox1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
gbc.ipady = 0;
gbc.weightx = 0.5D;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(jCheckBox1, gbc);
jInnerPanel.add(jCheckBox1);


JLabel jlLabel7 = new JLabel("Label 7 : ");
jlLabel7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
jlLabel7.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
jlLabel7.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(140, 20));
gbc.ipady = 0;
gbc.weightx = 0.5D;
gbc.weighty = 0.0D;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 6;

gbl.setConstraints(jlLabel7, gbc);
jInnerPanel.add(jlLabel7);

JComboBox jComboBox4 = new JComboBox();
jComboBox4.setEnabled(false);
jComboBox4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225, 20));
jComboBox4.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(225, 20));
jComboBox4.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(225, 20));
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 6;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
gbl.setConstraints(jComboBox4, gbc);
jInnerPanel.add(jComboBox4);

jpOPanel.add(jInnerPanel);

frame.add(jpOPanel);
```

CURRENT DISPLAY
[image]

EXPECTED DISPLAY
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the lines :

```
 gbl.setConstraints(jTextArea1, gbc);
 jpOPanel.add(jspane);
```

with

```
jspane.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
jpOPanel.add(jspane, gbc);
```

you need to set the `GridBagConstraints` of the component you're adding to the `jpOPanel` which is the `JScrollPanel` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir, it worked. But In my inner panel the check box and other 2 components are coming in the same line. What I want it is the checkbox should be on the first line and in second line the label and checkbox. both of it should be aligned to the inner panel border. Please refer image in original post for reference

Comment: @pankti First of all, you need to set the layout manager of `jInnerPanel` to a `GridBagLayout`, you can do this by `jInnerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout())`. Second, a good practice is for each `JComponent` to have it's own `GridBagConstraint`. If you do that for your `jCheckBox1` , `jlLabel7` and `jComboBox4` with the right `gridx` and `gridy` values you should get what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks a ton Mr.Lekili for your time and response.

Comment: Good call on accepting the answer. It helps people to find useful information in future (e.g. when I'm searching for answers I'll typically skip straight past any question that lacks an **accepted** answer). :)